# display details in ASP.net using URL parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am working on a website that generates data from a database with 6 columns.
One of the column is shortDescription and the other is FullDescription. I have added a link next to the shortDescription, "More" which must take to another page and display only the FullDescription from the database for each specific entry .. below is the code:

```
public partial class Events : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    public SqlDbType EventID { get; private set; }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            {
            SqlConnection Connection;
            SqlCommand Command;
            SqlDataReader Reader;
            string sql = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EventDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            Connection = new SqlConnection(sql);
            string CommandString = "SELECT * FROM Event ";
            Command = new SqlCommand(CommandString, Connection);
            Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            Command.Connection = Connection;
            Command.Connection.Open();
            Command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            string html  = "<table>";
            html += "<tr><td>Name</td><td>Type</td><td>NumTickets</td><td>EventDate</td><td>ShortDescription</td><td>ImageLocation</td></tr>";
            Reader = Command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
            if(Reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (Reader.Read())
                {
                    html += "<tr><td>"+ Reader["Name"]+"</td>";
                    html += "<td>" + Reader["Type"] + "</td>";
                    html += "<td>" + Reader["NumTickets"] + "</td>";
                    html += "<td>" + Reader["EventDate"] +  "</td>";
                    html += "<td>" + Reader["ShortDescription"] + " <a href='Events.aspx?id" + Reader["EventID"]  + "'> More</a>" + "</td>";
                    html += "<td><img src='App_Media\\" + Reader["ImageLocation"] +"'>"+ "</td><tr>";
                }
                html += "</table>";
                movieString.InnerHtml = html;
            }
            Command.Connection.Close();
            Command.Dispose();
            Connection.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

If someone knows how to achieve that using URL parameters, your input is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You nee to create another page: EventDetails.aspx and get id value from url for show long description.

Inside of EventDetails.aspx page you must to retrieve one row (by id) and show information using web controls, similar to Events.aspx page but adding WHERE clause for Sql command.

Sample code:

Events.aspx

```
public partial class Events : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            string sql = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EventDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            var connection = new SqlConnection(sql);

            var commandString = " SELECT * FROM Event ";

            var Command = new SqlCommand(commandString, connection);
            Command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            Command.Connection = connection;
            Command.Connection.Open();
            Command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            var html = "<table><tr><td>Name</td><td>Type</td><td>NumTickets</td><td>EventDate</td><td>ShortDescription</td><td>ImageLocation</td></tr>";

            var Reader = Command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

            if (Reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (Reader.Read())
                {
                    html += "<tr><td>" + Reader["Name"] + "</td>";
                    html += "<td>" + Reader["Type"] + "</td>";
                    html += "<td>" + Reader["NumTickets"] + "</td>";
                    html += "<td>" + Reader["EventDate"] + "</td>";
                    html += "<td>" + Reader["ShortDescription"] + " <a href='Events.aspx?id=" + Reader["EventID"] + "'> More</a>" + "</td>";
                    html += "<td><img src='App_Media\\" + Reader["ImageLocation"] + "'>" + "</td><tr>";
                }

                html += "</table>";

                movieString.InnerHtml = html;
            }

            Command.Connection.Close();
            Command.Dispose();

            connection.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Details.aspx

```
public partial class Details : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            var sql = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EventDBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

            var connection = new SqlConnection(sql);

            var commandString = " SELECT * FROM Event WHERE EventID = @eventID ";

            var eventID = -1;

            try
            {
                eventID = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["id"]);
            }
            catch
            {
                eventID = -1;
            }

            var command = new SqlCommand(commandString, connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            command.Connection = connection;
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@eventID", eventID));
            command.Connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            var html = "<table><tr><td>Name</td><td>Type</td><td>NumTickets</td><td>EventDate</td><td>ShortDescription</td><td>ImageLocation</td></tr>";

            var reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                reader.Read();

                // display values in controls

                movieString.InnerHtml = html;
            }

            command.Connection.Close();
            command.Dispose();

            connection.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Please don't use "SELECT * FROM ...", there are performance issues about use that kind of select, provides a select statement with each column name.

There are other improvements for this code:

1. Use an ORM to read data from database (Such as Entity Framework)
2. Use web controls to show information (GridView, etc)